# Passing arguments to printf

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int num=22;
   printf("%d %d %d", num,++num,++num);
}
```

The output of the above program is 24 24 24. Can someone explain?

Comment: Are you sure the output gives this? here n=22; but you are printing num? How's that possible? What value you have assigned to num?

Comment: It's num only. I edited it

Comment: I think its because when printf is evaluated num is already been incremented twice before it is displayed https://www.programiz.com/article/increment-decrement-operator-difference-prefix-postfix